# User/Auth Module in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am creating a User/Auth module for a website.
We have added a users page..basically example.com/user/userId.
My question is once a user is logged in how do i stop them from going to another users id page.
Say user 1234 has logged in and we send them to example.com/user/1234. What is the procedure for stopping a logged in user from going to example.com/user/231.

I was thinking of creating some auth_token when the user logs in and storing in the db and in the session..Something like:

```
$_SESSION[$id] = array(
    'token' => uniqid(),
    'name' => $user->getFName(),
);
```

Probably using something more secure to generate the token. But if i store this in the db and the session variable and then compare on every request this would make sure they cant get access to another page.

Or is there a better/easier way of doing this. I am new to user authentication and am not using a framework

Thanks

Comment: If you were [using a framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/), this would come as part of the package. Doing it yourself means re-inventing the wheel, and probably making a lot of mistakes in the process. User authentication is something you can get wrong many, many ways, so unless you've done it before, I'd advise you to use whatever a framework provides and not just copy-paste some dusty old tutorial code into your application.

Comment: I am not using a framework. This cant be that hard. Using a framework is not an option at this point, as that would require an entire rewrite of the application, which may occur at some point, but for now. Will my method work, basically if a user trys to go to a page that isnt there we will take the user_id param for the url string and compare the tokens, if they match then the user would get access, else redirected to there page

Comment: What I mean is an authentication system is a non-trivial bit of coding, and there's dozens of ways to screw it up badly. This is why using a framework from the outset helps. Maybe you're too late for that, or maybe you could find a way of wrapping your application in one. This session code might work for you, but how you apply it is the real challenge, making sure *all* pages are properly protected. As an example, WordPress screwed this up huge on several occasions.